# about wordpress custom permalink structure

Tags: wordpress

Can we maintain exactly same url from wordpress for summary page

```
domain_name/programs/early-childhood-development
```

and while clicking read more button go to this url

```
domain_name/programs/details/early-childhood-development
```

if possible then please help me

Comment: explain what is summary page.
do you mean when clicking on read more it should open the whole page of this article not only expanding the excerpt?

Comment: I am  using two editor in admin panel, one editor for summary text and other editor for full description of the page, I don't use excerpt, because my client wants text formatting in summary page too. so how is it possible to maintain above url structure?

Comment: could you please provide a link or summary page

Comment: here it is http://www.volunteeringnepal.org/programs/early-childhood-development and detail page link goes here: http://www.volunteeringnepal.org/programs/details/early-childhood-development and this is the domain name:http://www.volunteeringnepal.org , left hand side VOLUNTEER PROGRAMS are the list of all URL you can check , we want to rebuild this site in wordpress by maintaining same URL of volunteer programs page.

Comment: We have another site made in wordpress you can check http://www.volunteersinitiativenepal.org/ where I send variable to in url to identify it as a summary page http://www.volunteersinitiativenepal.org/teaching-program/english-at-buddhist-monastery-nunnery/?var1=summary , but for new site we want proper URL  without ?var1=summmary

Comment: I can do upto volunteeringnepal.org/programs/early-childhood-development but after clicking read more, can't maintain exactly same url for detail page: http://www.volunteeringnepal.org/programs/details/early-childhood-development